# Rails 2 way association not functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I have a bit of a problem. I've been developing a Rails app and have ran into a problem that I'm not able to fix.

As of now, my app allows users to enter product details into the database (stored in a 'products table') Here's the schema for the database I'm using.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140126073333) do

  create_table "ijns", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "number"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "quantity"
  end

  add_index "ijns", ["number"], name: "index_ijns_on_number"

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "ijn_id"
  end

  add_index "products", ["name"], name: "index_products_on_name"

end
```

There's another table called 'ijns' that assigns a unique identifier to each product. This ijn has not been made a primary key intentionally as I don't want it to be an auto incremented value.

The relation b/w IJN and Product is:

A product has_many ijns and 
An ijn belongs_to one product.

Here's my model for Product

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ijns
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, uniqueness: true
end
```

Model for IJN.

```
class Ijn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  validates :number, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { is: 4 }, numericality: {   only_integer: true }
  validates :product_id, presence: true
  validates :quantity, presence: true
end
```

I am able to get the association from the IJN side , ie, I'm able to access the fields of the product model by using something like:

```
@ijn.product.name
```

But I'm not able to access the 'number' field of the 'ijns' table from the product model

I hope I've been clear in explaining my problem. Please do let me know if additional info is required. Eagerly awaiting some replies! :)

1st Edit:

When i look at my 'products' table in the sqlite3 database browser, the column for ijn_id exists, but for some reason there are no entries. Here's a screenshot :

[image: Products Table in Database Browser]

[image: IJN table in Database Browser]

Comment: What have you tried? If you write `@product.ijns`, what do you get? A `NoMethodError` or something else?

Comment: Yeah Robin, I get a NoMethodError

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've defined a `Product` `has_many` `:ijns`.  This conflicts with a product having an  `ijn_id` like you have in your schema.

Thus when you try to do `product.ijn` you get an error.

Edit:

If a product really has many ijns then `ijn_id` makes no sense to ActiveRecord and the database.  They have no idea which ijn it is supposed to refer to.  I suspect that you want it to refer to the last ijn assigned to the product.

In that case one solution would be to change the attribute to something like `current_ijn_id`.  You will have to manually assign a value every time you need to update this.

Alternatively you could do `product.ijns.last`.  The problem is you will need to ensure that `.last` will give you the correct ijn every time.  It might not work for example, if for some reason you 'rollback' a product to an old ijn.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought.. i tried doing product.ijn_id.. that doesn't work either.. OK.. what do you suggest I do to fix this? I need 2 way access b/w the tables.. ijn.product.name is working.. i need 'product.ijn.number'..

Comment: Make the associations consistent.  So does a `Product` have one or many `Ijn`s?  If one, change the `has_many` to `has_one`.  ActiveRecord association basics: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Ok let me just clear something here. An instance of the product model can have only one IJN and an instance of the IJN model can have only one product. BUT, the same product can also be assigned another IJN during the lifecycle of the app. Doesn't this mean that a product has_many IJN s?

Comment: What happens when the product is assigned a new ijn, is the old one discarded?  If so, `has_one` is appropriate.  If not, i.e. a product accumulates ijns over time, use `has_many`.

Comment: Exactly.. its the latter.. the product accumulates IJN s over time. That's why I've used the has_many association. Like I said, its working from the IJN side, ie ijn.product.name returns the name of the product associated with the IJN but product.ijn.number doesn't return anything but a NoMethodError. Also, the ijn_id does not get updated in the products table as shown above..

Comment: So would that mean that what I'm trying to accomplish here is not possible? There must be a solution..

Comment: There are solutions, but they'll need a little work.  Did you read the edit?

Comment: Yeah I read it.. but I don't want to do it that way.. working on finding an easier method... Please do let me know if you find one

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're making this more complicated than you need:

---

**Table**

Your `ijn` number is like an [SKU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_keeping_unit) (unique identifier for YOUR system) right? As it's an attribute of the product, why you don't just put it in the products table:

```
 #products table
 id | ijn | name | created_at | updated_at
```

This immediately negates the requirement for an extra table (saves queries too)

---

**Extra**

If you want to call extra data for your `product`, you'll need a table specifically for that data

To me, a `model` is a collection of data with a specific purpose. Having a model for `ijn`'s does not constutue this

```
#app/models/products.rb
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile, class_name: "ProductProfile"
end

#app/models/product_profile.rb
Class ProductProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
end
```

This will allow you to call something like `@product.profile.quantity` or similar

Comment: Yeah I thought so as well.. that's why when I was deciding about the structure my db should take, I decided to put my products in a separate table coz it allows for scaling my application in the case that I need to add more attributes to my product model... That was basically the reason I used 2 separate tables. Also, since products will constantly be assigned to new unique values of IJN through the apps lifecycle, it's better to place it in it's own table.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts Product.first.ijn.number
```

This should work according to what you want to do.

Comment: Hey @murrekatt, I tried that but again, I get: "NoMethodError: undefined method `ijn' for #<Product:0x007ff76b065378>"

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your help... I did some more reading and found my solution.. For a one to many relationship like mine, you only need to provide the 'id' of the referenced table on one side, ie, including the 'product_id' column in the 'ijn' table. I deleted the 'ijn_id' column in the 'products' table and included one line of code in my 'ProductsController'. Here it is:

```
...
def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    #getting the related IJN
    @ijn = Ijn.find(:all, :conditions => ['product_id = ?',@product])
end

...
```

Now, in the view, the associated product name can be reference by simply doing

```
<% @ijn.map do |i| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=i.number %></td>
      <td><%= i.quantity %></td>
      <td><%= i.name %></td> #this returs the assocaiated product name
      <td><%= Date::MONTHNAMES[i.product.created_at.month] %></td>
      <td>placeholder</td>
      <td>placeholder</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Which returns the list of product names and associated IJNs. I haven't added any styling to my code above.

I hope this helps someone else who is facing a similar problem.